# Trying to get Flexget working on AsusWRT with opkg & pip

Tags: opkg

I'm getting an error after installing everything when running Flexget:

```
admin@RT-N16:/tmp/home/root# flexget -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bin/flexget", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2709, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 686, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: apscheduler
```

But apscheduler is installed.

```
admin@RT-N16:/tmp/home/root# pip install apscheduler
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): apscheduler in /tmp/mnt/Main/entware/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /tmp/mnt/Main/entware/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apscheduler)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): futures in /tmp/mnt/Main/entware/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apscheduler)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in /tmp/mnt/Main/entware/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apscheduler)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): tzlocal in /tmp/mnt/Main/entware/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from apscheduler)




Running setup.py install for flexget
    Checking .pth file support in .
    /opt/bin/python -E -c pass
    Searching for apscheduler
    Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/apscheduler/
    Best match: APScheduler 3.0.1
    Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/A/APScheduler/APScheduler-3.0.1.tar.gz#md5=7c3687b3dcd645fe9df48e34eb7a7592
    Processing APScheduler-3.0.1.tar.gz
    Running APScheduler-3.0.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /opt/tmp/easy_install-kKlzq_/APScheduler-3.0.1/egg-dist-tmp-dnfjW5
    installing library code to build/bdist.linux-mips/egg
    removing 'build/bdist.linux-mips/egg' (and everything under it)
    Extracting APScheduler-3.0.1-py2.7.egg to /tmp/mnt/Main/entware/tmp/pip-build-aruu_7/flexget
    Installed /tmp/mnt/Main/entware/tmp/pip-build-aruu_7/flexget/APScheduler-3.0.1-py2.7.egg

Successfully installed BeautifulSoup-3.2.1 FeedParser-5.1.3 PyRSS2Gen-1.1 SQLAlchemy-0.9.8 apscheduler-3.0.1
```